# How to disable same origin policy in Safari (Windows 7)?

Tags: safari, same-origin-policy

I'm trying to disable same origin policy in Safari (5.1.7.) on W7 station.

I'm doing phonegap application + jquery mobile + usage of rest services (drupal services 3.x module). I don`t have access to OSX now and need to test it without "Iphone simulator".

1. Is it possible to do tests with usage of W7 / Safari with disabled same-origin-policy?
2. Do I need to use file:// protocol to test it with Safari?

Thank you and greetings.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do:

```
C:\<path to installation>\Safari\Safari.exe --disable-web-security
```

but I'm on a Mac right now so I can't test for sure.

Comment: No, it doesn't work. I've tested it on Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bits with Safari 5.1.7.